# How to Build a neural network multi-output model using keras packet in R language?

Tags: r, keras

The structure of neural networks involves many parameter adjustments, how do adjust the following?  I sincerely hope that the scholars give advice.

```
model = keras_model_sequential() %>%    
  layer_dense(units = 150, activation = "tanh")  %>%
  layer_dense(units = 120, activation = "elu")  %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 80, activation = "relu")  %>% 
  layer_dense(units = out_dim, activation = "linear")
```

Answer (score 1):

Some things we may need to know to help you on your way -
what's the reasoning behind using 3 separate activation functions in the hidden layers?

What's the reasoning behind changing the number of units in each layer?

What kind of problem are we trying to solve here? What is a multiple-output model? Do you mean a multi-label output, i.e. an output for each category? Do you want this to be a probability distribution (i.e. with a softmax classification head, or is this intended to be  some form of regression problem?)

What form are your labels in? (this is linked to the previous question but it's important).

A more standard form of model for a probability distribution output - a multi-label, multi-class classification problem may be something like:

```
num_categories = 30 #The number of unique classes we are trying to classify into
model = keras_model_sequential() %>%    
  layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu")  %>%
  layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu")  %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu")  %>% 
  layer_dense(units = num_categories, activation = "softmax")
```

Of course we could have a differing number of units in each layer, but the question is 'why' and the answer ought not be 'because we can'. We could also have more or fewer layers, this tends to be something we need to tune and will depend on the problem at hand.

Then there are questions about the parameters of how the model is being compiled.

Which optimiser are you using, why?
Which loss function are you using, why?
Which metrics are you tracking, why?

To answer these questions will require some careful studying of the subject matter. There are a lot of good texts to be getting on with with, I'm not sure on the Stackoverflow rules about recommending texts etc. but I can say that personally I've found Francois Chollet's books on Deep Learning with Python to be very informative when using Keras (in R and Python),it's Chollet who created Keras.

Comment: Answer your questions sequentially.
1. The reason for choosing this neural network framework is the result of manual parameter tuning, which has achieved good research results in my previous research.
2. The solution is to predict the daily building energy consumption
3. First of all, this multi-output model is a regression model, not a classification model; secondly, multi-output means that when importing the model, the output parameters are multi-column instead of a single column.

Comment: 4. The output is in the form of 120 columns of daily building energy consumption, that is, the model can obtain the daily energy consumption for 120 days at the same time.
5. Selecting a different number of neurons, in the above and with the answer, is the result of manual adjustment. The reason for seeking automatic parameter tuning is that for my current research, manually tuning the parameters many times has the worst effect.
6. The detailed code about the optimizer and loss function is as follows.

Comment: model %>% compile(
  loss = "mse",
  optimizer = "adam")

model %>% summary()

set.seed(23659545)
system.time(history <- model %>% fit(xtrain_CL, ytrain_CL,
                                     epochs = 100, batch_size=50, verbose = 1))
scores = model %>% evaluate(xtrain_CL, ytrain_CL, verbose = 0)
print(scores)

Comment: Ok cool, so it's a multi-output regression problem. The architecture makes a bit more sense. So what is it that you would like to adjust, and why? Without knowing your data and the results you're getting, it's not really possible to advise too much further i think. It could be that your decision to use multiple activation functions is correct, I wouldn't be able to say without a much more intimate knowledge of your data. 100 epochs may be a lot, perhaps your learning rate is too low or your batch_size. Have you plotted the training + validation loss/accuracy?

Comment: The loss will be displayed during the modeling process, and the final printed loss is 7000+, which can be said to be very large. The effect obtained by using RMSE and R² is indeed very poor.
What I need to be clear is that I want to know how to automatically tune the parameters of this neural network, such as grid search, genetic algorithm, particle swarm optimization, etc. Is it feasible? If possible, how should it be done? Is there a corresponding R package that can implement automatic parameter tuning?

Comment: I see I see, well you should look into cross validation for neural nets.

Comment: Yes, so do you know the code for cross-validation of neural networks?  Can you provide it to me?  Thanks a million!

Comment: Sorry, it's a fairly time-intensive process and perhaps beyond the scope of what most people (including myself) will be willing to do on a SO question. If I were you I would probably do it with Caret, but tidymodels may also be compatible with Keras.